# how to serialize JSON and send it through Trigger every time edited and inserted?

Tags: webservices, json

I am just curious to know how to send JSON data with post method using @future call-outs to external system with a trigger (for after insert and update) , 
any one can help me to show some example on this scenario.

I am just trying to see outbound message of workflow but i can't send JSON format in it .

Help is appreciated. Thanks
sfdev

Comment: What data re you trying to send, is it List of Objects or Trigger.new/old or something else ?

Comment: I wanted to send list of records from 3 objects , Account and two custom objects

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the records to be sent in future method itself or you just want to send callout with JSON in future method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that for a [@future](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/passing-objects-to-future-annotated-methods.html) annotated method:

> one of the restrictions of future annotations is that you can not pass
>   sObjects or objects as arguments

you have to create the JSON string in the trigger and then pass it to the method:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    // This is sending an array
    Sender.post(JSON.serialize(Trigger.new))
}

public class Sender {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void post(String jsonString) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setBody(jsonString);
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can pass an Id or Ids and query in the class. As in your comment you say there are objects of different types involved, probably best to pass the Ids and query in the class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) class:

```
  // This creates json of an object/sObject/List instance
  String JSONString = JSON.serialize(innerClassORobjectInstance); 
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

  // set method type
  request.setMethod('POST');

  // send JSON by this
  request.setBody(JSONString);

  request.setEndpoint(EndpointURL_External_Webservice);
  request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

  // Finally send the request to external server
  HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
  System.debug('Response: response ' +response);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new appExchange app that let you do this without code:

Declarative Webhooks - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MSv8REAT

You can even do scheduled, and custom button in addition to making it triggered via Process Builder or Flow.

It has a free tier that you can try out before buying.